# xml document error when running a SQL Server Reporting services report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a SQL Server 2008 reporting services report which runs fine in preview mode using Visual studio 2008, but when I deploy it to the report server and run it there, it throws the following error. what does this error mean and how can I fix it? Thanks in advance.
"There is an error in XML document (1, 170604).
'.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character. Line 1, position 170604. "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your report parameters for unprintable control characters.

Comment: I just clicked on the report on the report server, didn't even select any values for the parameters and I am getting an error immediately. the parameters accept null values, not sure if that is an issue.

Comment: I just checked, the parameters are initialized to null as a default value in rdl file. do you think that is not allowed?

Comment: NULL parameters shouldn't be a problem. Check the data being returned by the report was well. You've got a bad character somewhere.